# Canceling subscription for all users and disabling auto renewal

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing, android-billing

Reading the documentation for subscriptions and related SO questions/answers i am still confused what to do when i have to stop providing the subscription services and content:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#cancellation

---

> In all cases, you must continue to offer the content that your
>   subscribers have purchased through their subscriptions, as long any
>   user is able to access it.

---

For example i am offering some content via my server to subscribed users in my app. At one point i am unable to offer that content and i want to cancel all subscriptions?

The users theoretically wont be able to access the content any more and i certainly dont want to charge them for it any longer. The proper use case for me would be to cancel the user subscriptions and refund the remaining money for them. But i am not sure that this is acceptable according to the available information in the docs...i guess that i can do the cancellation and refunds using the google play developer API (still reading the available options) if that will cover the policy requirements somehow?

I am just finding it hard to believe that if a user for ex. rejects app updates and stays on an old app version with an old subscription i have to support him for eternity :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you are suffering the only way around this is communicate to your users to update. Usually this case would mean a FORCE UPDATE so when they open your app they have to update. Your backend has to have a service like that. If user doesn't update they can't use the app. Also I pretty much believe that some subscriptions are auto renewal so that's one the reasons why deleting in the play store is not possible. Also take into account that change price would generate almost the same problem. Since you can't change a price of a subscription at least the base price, the country price you can.

Comment: Thnx...still was hopping that i was missing obvious that would give me an easy way out :D...i guess the update check/force will suffice.